# Turing recognizable - $B = \{a^n b^n c^n \}$

Tags: turing-machines

Question:
[image]

My answer is no, because it loops forever. But I am a bit unsure if this is the right answer.

Comment: What is "it" when you say "it loops forever?" What do you think "Turing-recognizable" means? What do you think the definition of $B$ means?

Comment: $B$ is a set of strings -- specifically the set that contains $\{abc, aabbcc, aaabbbccc, \dots\}$. So the question that's being asked above is: can you program a Turing machine so that it accepts these and only these strings?

Comment: **What** loops forever? Only a specific TM can do that. You claim that any TM recognizing $B$ must do so? Then how would it recognize $B$? Makes no sense.

Answer (score 2):

Construct a Turing machine that checks it is $a$s followed by $b$s and by $c$s, if not, reject. Go back to the beginning, cross out an $a$, a $b$ and a $c$, and start over at the beginning. If no uncrossed symbols remain, accept.

As it is accepted by the Turing machine outlined, the language is Turing recognizable.